# Change VPN gateway with command line

Tags: command-line, vpn

Is there a way to change the gateway of an existant VPN connection with a command line? 
Changing the gateway value in the connection file with sed doesn't work for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two ways to change the default gateway on a modern Linux system:

1. Using the traditional `route change default gw gateways_ip ethX`
   Advantage: Works on all unix like systems.
   Alternative: route delete follow by a route add. Do not try this when connecting remotely.
2. Using the `ip` command.
   ip route { add | del | change | append | replace | monitor } ROUTE

Comment: Maybe I should edit it to 'newer'. Personally I only discovered that command a year ago, despite using unix-alikes since 1991. (mostly slackware 2.4, 3, severals BSD etc etc).